# Numpy data loaded from file using memmap throws exception when used in formatted output

Tags: python, numpy

The following example demonstrates the issue.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.random.randn(10,3)
>>> np.save("x.npy", X)
>>> Y = np.load("x.npy", "r")
>>> Y.min()
memmap(-2.3064808987512744)

>>> print(Y.min())
-2.3064808987512744

>>> print("{}".format(Y.min()))
-2.3064808987512744

>>> print("{:6.3}".format(Y.min()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

Without the mode = 'r' in the load function, everything works as expected. Is this a bug? Or, am missing something?

Is there anyway to 'extract' the float value from the memmap to use it directly?

EDIT:

The 'item' method can be used to 'Copy an element of an array to a standard Python scalar and return it'. So, the following code works:

```
>>> print("{:6.3}".format(Y.min().item(0)))
  -2.31
```

Is there a rhyme or reason when you need to extract a value to use it?

Comment: I get this error with np 1.8.2 and Py3; I don't get it with np 1.9.0 and py2.7.  So there must have been some bug.  The `'{}'.format` mechanism depends on the object (in this a numpy array or datatype) implementing a `__format__` method.

Comment: How about falling back to the `%f` formatting method?  Even when it 'works', the formating isn't quite right, e.g. '-2.   ' instead of  ' -2.03'.   The new formatting method might still be poorly implemented for `numpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5543

> ndarray should offer **format** that can adjust precision

According to this issue, from last Feb,

```
n = np.array([1.23, 4.56])
print('{0:.6} AU'.format(n))
```

produces the same error

```
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

My guess is that `numpy` `memmap` objects have the same issue, and possible the same solution.

Evidently py3 style of `format` is still buggy, at least for add on packages like `numpy`.